# macOS keyboard layout switch bug

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, mojave, input-source

I have a problem that follows me from 2015 MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra → macOS High Sierra → macOS Mojave and now on to 2018 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave.

I have configured two input sources: English and Russian, and I prefer to switch between them with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key.

**The problem**: Some times switching does not work. I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and the layout stays the same. I press it again and it still stays. Eventually, it gets changed but it takes 5-6 <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key press.

This happens in both cases, US → RU and RU → US.

I have Siri disabled.

Comment: Is this with all applications or just particular ones?

Comment: I can't say exactly but seems like it happens in all apps. Also, I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Are you using the input sources provided by Apple, with the exact names "US" and "Russian"?  Or something else?

Comment: Are you able to test this using an external keyboard, to eliminate the possibility of a hardware fault?

Comment: @TomGewecke, U.S. and Russian yes. Provided by Apple. As I said, I have this issue on old MacBook Pro too. So this is definitely not a hardware issue.

Comment: Do you use *only* one key to switch, aka ```CapsLock``` or with a combination? Suggested by Apple is ```Ctrl+Space```

Comment: @Yoan Apple also suggests using Caps Lock alone, there is a box to check for this feature in input source preferences, and it normally works just fine.

Comment: Does this happen when you set up a temporary user account with the same keyboard settings? _Note: If you use an account with admin privileges, make sure the temp account is admin as well._

Comment: @IconDaemon, no. I have a single admin account.

Comment: when you push the Ctrl key does caps lock turn on? I had this issue this morning and I have no idea what caused it.

Comment: @BooleanCheese, no, CapsLock does not turn on

Comment: Same issue on Catalina. Very transient fix was to turn off-on layout switching w/ CapsLock option…

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. As I understand it, this is intentional behavior by Apple (they've been known to have additional delay on Caps Lock key to prevent accidental presses). Not many people notice this because it happens only when you type really fast (to reproduce just try spamming one key and press Caps Lock to switch the language at the same time – sometimes it would just be ignored).

There's a way to solve this – use [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). You can find how to set it up here: https://hybridtechcar.com/2018/07/01/turn-caps-lock-into-a-super-button-suitable-for-any-macbook/